# How to encode a StringVar from Entry box?

Tags: python-3.x, asciiencoding

There are some symbols which are **" 'ascii' codec can't encode character <\character-name> in position <\posiotion>: ordinal not in range(128)"** in my language and i want to get values of that type from Entry box so I have to encode but StringVar() cannot be encode and str() cannot be get(). So how can I encode a StringVar() in a entry or get() a str()?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.